# How can I disable or put a password on a process running in system tray?

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, process, notification-area

OS: Win XP SP3

User Role: Admin

I want to kind of lock a process (say bittorrent) which runs in system tray. I want that no one else who sits on my PC be able to EXIT/CLOSE that particular application.

Is it possible?

Comment: Nitpick - it's the "Notification Area" - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try [runas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runas)*. In that case, you might also want to [enable *Run As...*](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294676) in Explorer context menu.

If that doesn't do the trick, use [Fast User Switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_user_switching):

- create at least one more (or enable the *Guest*) account,
- use password protection for your screensaver,
- always lock (`Win + L`) your computer when leaving it unattended.

---

**Actually, it is highly recommended to make a habit of logging on as a limited account and using `runas` when elevated privileges are required. Somewhat like one would `sudo` on* **NIX systems.*

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

The nearest you can get is to use "Fast User Switch" with two user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Press Windows + L.

Comment: I want other user to use the same login...